# JSONDecodeError with json data

Tags: python, json

Actually,I am new to json-python, and i am getting error of simplejson.scanner.jsondecodeerror:expecting value Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0), i am trying for ["series"]["TimeStamp"] data

```
import urllib 
import simplejson
response = urllib.urlopen("http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/RUSHIL.NS/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/json")
#response.read()  //this works
data = simplejson.loads(response)
print data //error
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that your data has some unnecessary words. Response has `'finance_charts_json_callback('` at the first of data. So you should remove this function string. The following code shows.

```
import urllib 
import simplejson
response = urllib.urlopen("http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/RUSHIL.NS/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/json")
a = response.read()
a = a[29:-1] # remove function wrap
data = simplejson.loads(a)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that